# How to build minimum heap using buildHeap method and insert method?

Tags: c++, arrays, heap

I am new to programming I want to learn what is minimum heap and how to find minimum heap of a given array using `buildHeap` method and `insert` method

Comment: You need to specify some more context.

Comment: Which API is `buildHeap` from ?

Comment: C++ does not have methods.It has functions :)

Answer (score 0):

To learn Min Heap you must first learn what a Binary Heap is.
A Binary Heap is a Binary Tree with following properties.
1) It’s a complete tree (All levels are completely filled except possibly the last level and the last level has all keys as left as possible). This property of Binary Heap makes them suitable to be stored in an array.

2) A Binary Heap is either Min Heap or Max Heap. In a Min Binary Heap, the key at root must be minimum among all keys present in Binary Heap. The same property must be recursively true for all nodes in Binary Tree.

To insert element 'K' into a Min Heap :

```
void MinHeap::insertKey(int k)
{
    if (heap_size == capacity)
    {
        cout << "\nOverflow\n";
        return;
    }
    heap_size++;
    int i = heap_size - 1;
    harr[i] = k;
    while (i != 0 && harr[parent(i)] > harr[i])
    {
       swap(&harr[i], &harr[parent(i)]);
       i = parent(i);
    }
}
```

I don't know any `buildheap` or `insert` functions but c++ stl has `make_heap()` and `push_heap()` functions for the same purpose.
[Heap c++ implementation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-using-stl-c/)

Comment: which method you used?